# Webgl Vector Array

Tags: javascript, vector, webgl

I am trying to make A cube of triangles using JavaScript and Webgl. The cube will use face edge vertex structure using arrays , but when I use arrays there is nothing drawn to screen.
This how I declare the array.

```
function Vector(x,y,z){
this.x = x; 
this.y = y;
this.z = z;
}

var V = new Array;
V[0] = new Vector(0.0,  1.0,  0.0);
V[1] = new Vector(-1.0, -1.0,  0.0);
V[2] = new Vector(1.0, -1.0,  0.0);


function initBuffers() {
    triangleVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
    var vertices = [
        V[0],
        V[1],
        V[2]
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 1;
    triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 3;
```

I am not sure why it doesn't draw to screen if anyone can help it would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that all your code? Have you setup the GL context correctly? Can you create a jsFiddle so we can see all of your code?

Comment: I have never used jsFiddle but here is a link with my code on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J8Wkg/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the following line:

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

`new Float32Array(vertices)` is returning `[NaN, NaN, NaN]`. This is because the `Float32Array` contructor expects an array of `Number`s and not an array of `Vector`s.

You'll need to pass `new Float32Array()` a single one dimensional array of `Number`s

If you want to fix it you'll have to write a function to convert your array of `Vector`s into a `Float32Array`. Something like this:

```
function vectorsToFloatArray(vertices) {
    var numbers = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        numbers.push(vertices[i].x);
        numbers.push(vertices[i].y);
        numbers.push(vertices[i].z);
    }

    return new Float32Array(numbers);
}
```

And remember to update the `gl.bufferData()` and item size:

```
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vectorsToFloatArray(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I now have it working do you know how to make an array that will take two vectors E[0] = [V[0], V[1]]; and then use that to draw to the screen